# Django sessions is not working

Tags: django, session, wsgi

i'm trying to find bug for few hours now but nothing comes out.

Django gives me this error message when i'm trying to access `request.SESSION` from view. No other errors.

> `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'SESSION'`

Here is my Django settings what points to sessions and authentication. Most of them are set to their defaults.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE     = 'alkimikis.users.models.UserProfile'
INSTALLED_APPS          = ['django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.admin', 'alkimikis.users']
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES      = ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')
SESSION_ENGINE          = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

Ideas for solution or deeper debugging? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `request.session`.  Lower case.

To debug, use the unit test framework.  You can then add `print` statements and see the results.

```
print request
```

Very helpful.

Comment: OK. No more programming today. Thanks. I think its bad PHP influence.

Comment: @Anpher: You might want to click the "accept" tick mark if this actually solved your problem.